# ¿Por que evento focus se dispara 2 veces?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un INPUT, intento que al hacer focus sobre él la fecha actual se registre automáticamente. Al hacer focus mando un mensaje para preguntar si esta seguro de registrar la fecha actual (podría haber un error de dedo) y aquí esta mi problema, pues el mensaje se repite 2 veces y no entiendo por que. El mensaje lo muestro con el plugin JQUERYCONFIRM.

```
$('.fecha').on('focus',function() {

    var hoy = new Date();
    var dia = hoy.getDate();
    var mes = hoy.getMonth()+1;
    var año = hoy.getFullYear();

    if(dia<10) {dia='0'+dia;} 
    if(mes<10) {mes='0'+mes;}    

    hoy = año + '-' + mes + '-' + dia;

    //$(this).val(hoy);

    $.confirm({
        theme: 'material',
        title: 'Atencion',
        content: '¿Ingresar Fecha?',
        useBootstrap: false,
        boxWidth:'300px',
        buttons:{
            Adelante: function(){ ingresarFecha() },
            Cancelar: function(){}
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Hace una prueba: comenta el toda la función y solo usa un console.log("prueba"); se imprime en consola dos veces? Por que quizás es un problema de Jquery Confirm

Comment: Si. Tienes razón, ya hice pruebas y el evento se dispara 2 veces solo cuando uso el jqueryconfirm. Al menos ahora se donde esta el problema, aunque aun no se como solucionarlo.

Comment: Probá poniendo el $.confirm en una función aparte, y llamala dentro de la función del focus

Comment: Lo he intentado como me has dicho, pero sigue disparándose 2 veces :/

Comment: Intentar con `$(this).confirm({ ....});` para llamar a la confirmación.

Comment: @Dev.Joel Lo he intentado con $(this).confirm({...}); y me funciona bien cuando hago click, pero ya no me aparece el mensaje cuando hago Focus.

Comment: @OscarDíaz añadir el código final incluido el html.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es asegurarte de que esa función se ejecute solo una vez cuando ocurra el evento usa **`unbind()`**, con tu código quedaría:

```
$('.fecha').unbind().on('focus',function() {

        var hoy = new Date();
        var dia = hoy.getDate();
        var mes = hoy.getMonth()+1;
        var año = hoy.getFullYear();

        if(dia<10) {dia='0'+dia;} 
        if(mes<10) {mes='0'+mes;}    

        hoy = año + '-' + mes + '-' + dia;

        //$(this).val(hoy);

        $.confirm({
            theme: 'material',
            title: 'Atencion',
            content: '¿Ingresar Fecha?',
            useBootstrap: false,
            boxWidth:'300px',
            buttons:{
                Adelante: function(){ ingresarFecha() },
                Cancelar: function(){}
            }
        });

    });
```

No obstante puedes usar en vez de **`unbind()`** la función **`off()`**.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda

Comment: He probado las 2 funciones pero sigue apareciendo 2 veces el mensaje :/

Comment: @OscarDíaz vaya! Entonces me dejas sin palabras, aún así... podrías facilitar tu código html y css?

Comment: Como me han comentado arriba, al parecer es un problema que tiene que ver con el plugin jqueryconfirm, porque cuando quito esa parte del código funciona bien. Y probando como me han dicho en el otro comentario esto $(this).confirm({...}) en lugar de $.confirm({...}) lo que sucede es que funciona bien mostrando 1 vez el mensaje, el problema es que entonces el evento ya solo se dispara con click y ya no con focus. No se si esto te ayude a entender mejor el problema, si no con gusto muestro el html y css.